# Redis info doesn't update after client was previously disposed

Tags: c#, servicestack.redis

I am using `ServiceStack.Redis` version `4.0.56` to read and display Redis server information as shown in the class below:

```
using ServiceStack.Redis

class Test
{
    private IRedisClientManager clientManager;

    public Test()
    {
        clientManager = new PooledRedisClientManager(10, 10, connectionString);
    }

    public IDictionary<string, string> GetInfo()
    {
         var redisClient = redisClientManager.GetClient();
         var info = redisClient.Info;

         // If commented out, all info values are updated (i.e. uptime, keys etc)
         redisClient.Dispose();

         return info;
    }
}
```

The problem is, as soon as the client is disposed (per best-practice), the `Info` property of `redisClient` always returns the old values, even though I obtain a new client instance as shown in the `GetInfo` method above.

When I leave out the `redisClient.Dispose` call, the `Info` values are all updated.

What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After posting this [as an issue in Github](https://github.com/ServiceStack/Issues/issues/442), the ServiceStack team members were quick to respond.

The reason was that the RedisClient caches the `INFO` command and does not update data on subsequent calls or after disposing and using it with the client manager.

**This has been fixed in `ServiceStack.Redis` `v4.0.59`.**